# Audit privileges across all PostgreSQL objects

Tags: postgresql, privileges, audit

I would like to audit the privileges in my PostgreSQL database. How can I generate a table of roles and their privilege grants across all database objects?

For tables I can query `information_schema.role_table_grants`. I can also do similar queries for other database objects, but I worry that I might miss an object type, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

not inventing the wheel I'd start from `psql -E`:

```
t=# \z
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(c.relacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(
    SELECT attname || E':\n  ' || pg_catalog.array_to_string(attacl, E'\n  ')
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
    WHERE attrelid = c.oid AND NOT attisdropped AND attacl IS NOT NULL
  ), E'\n') AS "Column privileges",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(
    SELECT polname
    || CASE WHEN polcmd != '*' THEN
           E' (' || polcmd || E'):'
       ELSE E':'
       END
    || CASE WHEN polqual IS NOT NULL THEN
           E'\n  (u): ' || pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(polqual, polrelid)
       ELSE E''
       END
    || CASE WHEN polwithcheck IS NOT NULL THEN
           E'\n  (c): ' || pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(polwithcheck, polrelid)
       ELSE E''
       END    || CASE WHEN polroles <> '{0}' THEN
           E'\n  to: ' || pg_catalog.array_to_string(
               ARRAY(
                   SELECT rolname
                   FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles
                   WHERE oid = ANY (polroles)
                   ORDER BY 1
               ), E', ')
       ELSE E''
       END
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_policy pol
    WHERE polrelid = c.oid), E'\n')
    AS "Policies"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', 'm', 'S', 'f')
  AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
**************************
```

Comment: Wow, nice one! This is a good start, although there are still many other object types to look at.